# Is it possible to include one HAProxy backend in another?

Tags: haproxy

We're running multiple sites on the same hardware, and we'd like to serve them using the same pool of application machines.  However, one site periodically gets greatly-increased traffic, and so we'd like to reserve a small section of machines for only the other sites.

Is it possible to do something like this in HAProxy?

```
backend foo
    server app00 0.0.0.0 cookie app00 check
    server app01 0.0.0.0 cookie app00 check
    server app02 0.0.0.0 cookie app00 check

backend bar
    server app03 0.0.0.0 cookie app03 check
    include foo
```

I realize that we could simply define the machines in multiple rules, but I'd rather avoid duplication if possible.

Comment: I don't see anything in the manual that seems to prevent this. Couldn't you just try it?

Comment: Well, I didn't see anything in the manual that indicates there's an `include` statement, either. ;)  FWIW, I tried it, and there is indeed no `include` statement allowed in `backend` clauses.

Comment: So it looks like this will never happen.  Bummer.